# Does "226 Transfer complete" guarantee the consistency between local and remote files when using ftp?

Tags: networking, ftp, error-handling

I have some automated scripts which perform FTP uploads among other things. I'm wondering what level of error checking I should conduct once these uploads have finished executing.

Could anything go wrong uploading a file when it reports `"226 Transfer complete"` which would warrant extra tests, besides checking for this string in the log, to check if a file was successfully uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. 226 can also occur on various conditions where this would not be true (`ABORT` for one). See [RFC 959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt).

Comment: Presumably the OP knows he isn't issuing an ABORT command, which to my knowledge, no servers support and no clients issue anyhow.

Comment: It is the only command for which 226 does not mean the data has been successfully transferred.

Answer (score 0):

MD5SUM or SHA1SUM may do the trick.

The problem then is that you either have to compute the checksum on the server you're uploading to or download the file from the server and compare. But that could also mean it wasn't downloaded properly...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by guarantee.  226 means the transfer finished without any error detected, so barring an undetected error corrupting the data, or the server crashing before it can commit it to disk from its cache or something, the files will be identical.